# Suche bestimmtes deutsches Wort für »brainstorming«

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, synonym

Ich suche ein deutsches Wort für *brainstorming.*

Es findet sich recht viel per Google, aber ich suche ein ganz bestimmtes – wie ich fand, »geiles«, lustiges deutsches – Wort beziehungsweise Synonym.
Es gab ja wohl schon oft Umfragen diverser Institute und Personen diesbezüglich und ich meine ganz dunkel mich an eine gute Auswahl von Bastian Sick erinnern zu können.
Es war nicht *Ideengewitter* oder *Hirnyoga,*  aber ein ähnliches zusammengesetztes Wort.

Comment: Ideenfindung, Ideensammlung, Denkrunde?

Comment: nein, es war abstrakter und deutlich lustiger, weniger sachlich.... :)

Comment: Gehirnbrausen, Gripsbrodeln?

Comment: Warum mit allen möglichen Verrenkungen ein neues Wort suchen, wenn es doch schon einen etablierten und allgemein bekannten Begriff gibt? Was ist denn schlecht an »Brainstorming«?

Comment: es geht teils nur um's Prinzip. Man muß es abwägen. Aber nach 5 Minuten Werbefernsehen sollte jedem klar sein, daß man hin und wieder aktiv einschreiten sollte.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Was ist schlecht an Pferdedroschken?

Comment: @userunknown: Am Wort »Pferdedroschke« ist nichts schlecht. Daher würde ich auch nicht krampfhaft nach einem anderen Wort für diesen Gegenstand suchen wollen. Hier geht es um Wörter, nicht um die damit bezeichneten Dinge. Die Qualität der Methode, die mit »Brainstorming« oder einem anderen Wort bezeichnet wird, steht ja nicht zur Diskussion, sondern die Qualität ihres Namens. Und ich finde, von allen Namen, die hier zu lesen sind, ist »Brainstorming« der beste, was mich eben fragen lässt, wozu man überhaupt einen anderen Namen suchen soll. Denn alle genannten Alternativen klingen kindisch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Synapsentango***

> Allein Brainstorming erbrachte mehr als dreitausend verschiedene
>   Vorschläge von mehr als 10.000 Einsendern, darunter Gripstreff,
>   Hirnhatz, Synapsentango.

Siehe:

- http://deutschesprachwelt.de/archiv/papier/DSW33.pdf
- https://phinau.de/jf-archiv/archiv08/200848112156.htm